# JPA/HIBERNATE CRUD repository - update in parent entity will add duplicate child instances into DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, crud

I have 2 classes (ONE to MANY mapping).

**Parent class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent{
        
@Id
private int ParentId;
    
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parent")
private List<Child> childEntities;
```

**Child class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class Child{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int childId;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
private Parent parent;
```

When I want to save parent object do database with parentRepository.save(parent) everything is right. Parent and Child are saved into database. The problem is, when I want to perform parentRepository.save(parent) on parent that is already in the database (JPA will do update - it updates parent table, but in child table it inserts new rows). The parent table is right, but in child table I have duplicate values. Primary Key in child is SERIAL (I use Postgres db).

Lets say I have empty database and I have these two lines of code:

**parentRepository.save(parent);**

**parentRepository.save(parent);**

After these two lines I will have single row in table parent in database, but every of his children is in table child twice.

Comment: what if you remove all "cascade" attributes from annotations? will this problem still be present?

Comment: I removed "cascade=CascadeType.ALL" from parent. It saved data only into parent table, but no into child table(db was empty before inserting).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using `@GeneratedValue`, the child entity id will be generatet when you call `sava` for the first time.

If you check the [save method documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-), you will see that it does return a new instance of the object you saved.

This new instance contains the parent entity with the child entities with the ids generated by spring on those child entities.

Another important change you need to do is to use wrapper types instead of primitives in the attributes annotated with `@Id`. Wrappers can contain a `null` value, this is important for spring to know if the entity is a new entity or is an entity to be updated. Check [spring-data-jpa docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites) for more information.

The problem with your code is *first* that you are using primitive type attributes annotated with `@Id` (change it to wrapper types) and the *second* is that you are supposed to use the returned object from the `save` method for further operations.